# I Want to fetch directors and actors who have not worked together in a movie yet

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
create table movie
(
id int,
moviename nvarchar(255),
year INT
);



create table director
(
id int,
directorname nvarchar(255),
);


create table artists
(
id int,
artistname nvarchar(255),
gender varchar(255)
);


create table relation 
(
movieid int,
person_id int,
role varchar(255)

);




insert into movie
select 1 , 'AAG' , '2000'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'DON'  , '2009'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,'SIVAJI' , '2004'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,  'NEWYAER' , '2018';




insert into DIRECTOR
select 1 , 'RGV'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'FARHAN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'SHANKAR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 'AKTHAR';


INSERT INTO ARTISTS
SELECT 1 , 'ABHISHEK' , 'M'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'SRK', 'M'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'RJK', 'M';




INSERT INTO RELATION
SELECT 1 , 1 , 'DIRECTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 , 1 , 'ACTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 2 , 'DIRECTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 2 , 'ACTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 3 , 'DIRECTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 3, 'ACTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 4 , 'DIRECTOR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 1 , 'ACTOR';



SELECT DISTINCT F.artistname , E.directorname,E.id FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM RELATION WHERE ROLE = 'DIRECTOR') A
, (SELECT * FROM DIRECTOR ) B
WHERE A.person_id = B.id
)E FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM RELATION WHERE ROLE = 'ACTOR') C
, (SELECT * FROM artists ) D
WHERE C.person_id = D.id
) F
ON E.movieid  <>  F.movieid;




;
```

Comment: So what is your question? "I want" isn't asking anything, and dumping some SQL into a question doesn't make it a question. What about what you have isn't working? Even if it is, I doubt it's the most efficient.

Comment: also, I see no relation between director and movie - you should [edit] your question adding more details and the expected result. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Use also dbfiddle.uk for create a working sample - like [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c60a1be61e71475c850d95172d103cf) I was trying to create for understand your question.

Comment: I think as a new member we should guide him to write a good question instead of downvoting him since he has provided detail table structures with insert statements for sample data along with his effort. Yes question could be more clear and a desired output would be great. But it's much more informative than many other questions.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes If I am not wrong in relation table relation between director and movie exists.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur you're right. Thanks for the feedback. I was guided by the name of the columns rather than the data in the relation table.

Comment: @vinayak You did excellent work by providing all necessary information to recreate the situation. Please always add your desired output with an explanation for avoiding downvoting and to help others to help you solving problems.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur the downvotes are denoting the usefulness and clarity to *other* users as well as the OP. What is clear about this question? There isn't one. They've just dumped some SQL in a question and expect us to infer the requirements. If the OP really wants to get rid of those downvotes, they will edit their question to make it useful and clear. Downvotes aren't unwelcoming, they are telling users (all of them) about the quality of the question.

Comment: Also, @KaziMohammadAliNur , don't assume users here are male. The OP hasn't told us anywhere what gender they are, so per the networks rules/guidelines you should be using gender neutral language.

Comment: @Larnu agree with you. Downvotes are also extremely necessary. I was just considering OP's experience in stackoverflow. And thanks for reminding me. I will try to use gender neutral language.

Comment: @kazi Thanks. And I am sorry as i used stack overflow for the first time and I thought giving all table structiure and data is enough. Next time I will try to be more specific.

Comment: @Vinayak you are most welcome. Though your problem might have been resolved but you can edit this question to make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table movie
 (
 id int,
 moviename nvarchar(255),
 year INT
 );
           
 create table director
 (
 id int,
 directorname nvarchar(255),
 );
      
 create table artists
 (
 id int,
 artistname nvarchar(255),
 gender varchar(255)
 );
      
 create table relation 
 (
 movieid int,
 person_id int,
 role varchar(255)
 
 );               
 
 insert into movie
 select 1 , 'AAG' , '2000'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 'DON'  , '2009'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 ,'SIVAJI' , '2004'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 4,  'NEWYAER' , '2018';
                
 insert into DIRECTOR
 select 1 , 'RGV'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 'FARHAN'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 'SHANKAR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 , 'AKTHAR';     
 
 INSERT INTO ARTISTS
 SELECT 1 , 'ABHISHEK' , 'M'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 'SRK', 'M'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 'RJK', 'M';          
      
 INSERT INTO RELATION
 SELECT 1 , 1 , 'DIRECTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 , 1 , 'ACTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 2 , 'DIRECTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 , 2 , 'ACTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 3 , 'DIRECTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 , 3, 'ACTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 , 4 , 'DIRECTOR'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 , 1 , 'ACTOR';
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
     select d.movieid,d.person_id directorid,a.person_id actorid from
     (select * from relation where role='DIRECTOR') d 
     inner join 
     (SELECT * FROM relation where role='Actor') a
     on d.movieid=a.movieid
 )
 select artistname,directorname,d.id from director d cross join artists a
 where not exists 
                (
                    select 1 from cte where cte.directorid=d.id and cte.actorid=a.id
                )
 order by d.id,a.id
```

Output:

| artistname | directorname | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SRK | RGV | 1 |
| RJK | RGV | 1 |
| ABHISHEK | FARHAN | 2 |
| RJK | FARHAN | 2 |
| ABHISHEK | SHANKAR | 3 |
| SRK | SHANKAR | 3 |
| SRK | AKTHAR | 4 |
| RJK | AKTHAR | 4 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e1dcf0c09e9725de2f2d64905c8ecb23)*

Answer (score 0):

Start with all combinations of director and actor, then exclude combinations that you can find in the relations table.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  director
CROSS JOIN
  actor
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      relation  AS d
    INNER JOIN
      relation  AS a
        ON a.movie_id = d.movie_id
    WHERE
          d.role      = 'DIRECTOR'
      AND d.person_id = director.id
      AND a.role      = 'ACTOR'
      AND a.person_id = actor.id
  )
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  director.id,
  actor.id
FROM
  director
CROSS JOIN
  actor

EXCEPT

SELECT
  d.person_id,
  a.person_id
FROM
  relation  AS d
INNER JOIN
  relation  AS a
    ON a.movie_id = d.movie_id
WHERE
      d.role      = 'DIRECTOR'
  AND a.role      = 'ACTOR'
```